# Automatic start of jconsole from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jmx, jconsole

I wondered if there is a plugin or someone has a script to start jconsole automatically when I run or debug an application from eclipse. Maybe adding the classpath too. I googled but didnt find anything. In most cases this is a sign that it doesnt work or its to easy to ask :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a plugin for **VisualVM** (http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html) which does exactly this.

Given that **VisualVM** is a superset of the **jConsole** and it also supports **jConsole** plugins natively you can safely use **VisualVM** instead of **jConsole**.

Comment: It seems, that I cant add Launchers to all sort of java applications running from eclipse. For example TestNG or GWT apps.

Comment: This link is broken and plugin is not available now

Answer (score 2):

This is not about automatic start, but it is about connecting the program running in eclipse through jvisualvm.

In eclipse, in the Main class java file do the below, then run as java application.

```
Right click --> Run As --> Run Configuration --> Arguments --> VM argumanets --> Add the below

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostname -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10001
```

Then open java visaul vm  from JDK bin directory. In that

```
File --> Add JMX Connection --> In connection text box --> localhost:10001
```

This will start your profiling now.

Comment: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostname is important though you are running the program locally.